# How can I make VirtualBox guests(Windows) VPN share with the host's (Ubuntu)

Tags: virtualbox, windows, vpn

Forticlient VPN doesn't support `IpSec`in Ubuntu. So I tried to set up Windows in Virtual box (Guest).

How to share guest (Windows OS) VPN with Host OS (Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I have your same problem with another VPN Client, but I have not found a way to share the guest VPN with the host yet.

However, even if it does not actually answer your question, have you tried looking at [openfortivpn](https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn)? I think it provides a better VPN client for Linux based systems than the official one (it has better CLI support). Maybe you can solve your problem using it directly on your host environment.